# QSystemTrayIcon in a Qt5 Designer Ui file

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget

I am trying to load all my forms from the Ui files with QUiLoader. I ran into the problem with QSystemTrayIcon. For some reason QFormBuilder fails to load my form.

My Ui file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
    <class>SystemTrayIcon</class>
    <widget class="QSystemTrayIcon" name="SystemTrayIcon">
        <property name="icon">
            <iconset>:/icons/tray_icon.png</iconset>
        </property>
    </widget>
    <resources/>
    <connections/>
</ui>
```

And I load it with the following code:

```c
tray_icon tray_icon_factory::build()
{
    QUiLoader loader;
    QFile file(":/forms/tray_icon.ui");

    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QWidget *widget = loader.load(&file);
    file.close();

    tray_icon the_tray_icon(widget);
    return the_tray_icon;
}
```

When I compile and run my application I get the following error:

```
"QFormBuilder was unable to create a widget of the class 'QSystemTrayIcon'."
```

What I am doing wrong and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSystemTrayIcon` is not a widget, so you can't create it from an ui file.

Comment: I felt that something like this could be messing up my day. Maybe there is a way to put tray icon inside a widget and describe it as it's component? Or I have to have a dedicated class for it?

Comment: You could add the icon (the image, not the `QSystemTrayIcon` object) to a `QAction` in an .ui file, retrieve the action with `QUiLoader::createAction` and extract its icon, and finally create the `QSystemTrayIcon` manually to assign the icon and possibly a menu from that same .ui file. If that is what you are asking...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I took a bit different approach and redesigned code a bit. But your comment answers my question. Thank you! :)